# .htaccess redirect/rewrite many domains to many domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My idea is:

- requests to service.example.com should be redirected to service.example.com,
- all the other requests to example.com should be redirected to base.example.com

My host is configured in such a way, that there is example.com directory, and all subdomains live in their subdirectories (example.com/service, example.com/base, etc.).

How can I achieve the needed redirections?

I have tried with RedirectMatch, RewriteCond, RewriteRule, but with no results. My try was:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://base.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked only for the base.example.com. For service.example.com, there was loop of rewrites/redirections.

I could only find examples of simple rewrites, one domain -> other domain, or many domains -> one domain, yet my case is different: its many domains -> many other domains.

EDIT: OK, I got it with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://base.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The key was to use a rule to do nothing: `- [L]`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://base.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Or, simply...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(base|service)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://base.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

HOWEVER... If you are placing this `.htaccess` file in the parent directory (which I assume you must be) then this probably won't work as intended, since the "hidden" subdirectory (that the subdomain points to) will also be captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and included in the redirect. (Or is that the intention?!)

For example, given a subdomain `foo` that points to the corresponding subdirectory `example.com/foo` and you request `http:://foo.example.com/bar`, then the above directive will redirect the request to `http://base.example.com/foo/bar`, not `http://base.example.com/bar` (which I assume would be the intention). This is because the `RewriteRule` *pattern* captures the file-path (that the URL maps to) in this context, not the URL-path.

To resolve this, you would need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead, which holds the requested root-relative URL-path.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(base|service)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://base.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change it to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it all works OK.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.